# isVideoOrientationSupported always Returns NO AVCaptureConnection

Tags: ios, avcapturesession, avcapture

I'm using `AVCaptureMetadataOutput` to detect faces on iOS, and I'm trying to set the orientation of the video after the user rotates their device. However, it appears that I can't do this as every time I call the getter `isVideoOrientationSupported` on the only AVCaptureConnection that my `AVCaptureMetadataOutput` has, it always returns false. I've tried the code below in every place imaginable, yet it always returns no. Is there any way to set orientation for my metadata?

```
AVCaptureConnection *conn = [self.metadataOutput connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeMetadataObject];

    NSLog(@"%@",self.metadataOutput.connections);

    if (!conn) {
        NSLog(@"NULL CONNECTION OBJ");
    }

    if ([conn isVideoOrientationSupported]) {
        NSLog(@"Supported!");
    }

    else {
        NSLog(@"Not supported");
    }
```

Comment: Any leads on this?

Comment: @TarunG I posted an answer. Check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Apple Engineer solved this for me over on the Apple Developer Forums. Here's a [link](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/152577#152577). This was their response:

> If you want to translate your metadata objects' coordinate space to
>   that of another `AVCaptureOutput` (such as the
>   `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput`), use
>   `- (AVMetadataObject *)transformedMetadataObjectForMetadataObject:(AVMetadataObject *)metadataObject connection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);`   It's in AVCaptureOutput.h.   If you want to
>   translate the coordinates to the coordinate space of your video
>   preview layer, use AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.h's
>   `- (AVMetadataObject *)transformedMetadataObjectForMetadataObject:(AVMetadataObject *)metadataObject NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);`